# Making launch image disappear faster

Tags: ios, objective-c

In order to make my app launch faster so I can start contacting with the server I made `AppDelegate` launch fast by cleaning all kind of work like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //[self redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder];
    [[Ubertesters shared] initialize];
    return YES;
}
```

What I want to achieve is loading my app faster to splash screen and show in the middle of the screen some kind of spinner (`SVProgressHUD` or `UIActivityIndicatorView`), so far I'm putting the spinner in the splash screen `viewWillAppear`.

This is what happens: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions load fast, then SplashScreen-viewDidLoad load fast and then `viewWillAppear` took a few seconds, but most of the way I see the image I set up as launch image and not my `SplashScreen` image with spinner animation.

Any ideas how can I make the launch image disappear faster and show my animation?

Comment: Splash screen is shown from the point when You tap on the icon, until it has fully awaken application / launched it. Indeed - if You remove unnecessary things from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (and possibly launch them after a delay) - App will launch much faster.

Comment: I did a 1 second delay in my SplashScreen class and still I see the original launch image.

Comment: Original launch image will be seen always. Your SplashScreen class will/can be visible (if correctly implemented) only after original Splash screen.

Only thing You can do is set default splash screen graphic to black image or white image, so that no one would suspect that that was the splash screen.

Comment: My SplashScreen class implemented correctly, and I still show the launch image in this class, but I'm adding a spinner. Spinner in launch image could be perfect.

Comment: So the problem is that You don't see Your SplashScreen with spinner? That means You did not implement it correctly.